# Why is break() not working in this loop? (but stop is)

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, break

I am trying to build a matrix model which ends if certain conditions are invoked - however for some reason the break() command isn't working, although stop() does. Unfortunately stop() is not what I need as I need to run the model a number of times.

The first break command in the model works, but I have left it in with dth>100 so that you can see for yourselves

```
    n.steps <- 200
ns <- array(0,c(14,n.steps)) 
ns[13,1]<-rpois(1,3)
ns[14,1] <- 1 
k<-0

for (i in 1:n.steps){
  k<-k+1
  ns[13,1]<-rpois(1,2)
  death<-sample(c(replicate(1000, 
                            sample(c(1,0), prob=c(surv.age.a, 1-surv.age.a), size = 1))),1)
  ns[14,k] <- death

  if (death == 0) {
    dth <- sample(1:100, 1)
    if (dth > 100) {
      ns[14,k]<-0
      print("stop.1")
      break()

    } else {

      while (death == 0) {
        if (ns[13, k] > 0) {
          rep.vec[i]<-ns[13,k]

          ns[13, k] <- ns[13, k] - 1
          ns[14,k+1]<-1
          print("replace")

        } else {

          if (ns[13, k] == 0) {
            print("stop.2")
            ns[14,k+1]<-0
            break()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use `break` not  `break()`, it's not  function.

Comment: still doesn't work sadly :'(

Comment: also strangely the prior break() command does work so I wouldn't have thought it could have been that

Comment: `break` will take you out of the innermost loop, it will not stop the execution: in this case it will take you out of `while` loop not the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Is there any way of getting out of the for loop? Other than stop() which kills everything, including the loop this loop is nested in

Comment: Wait I've got it - there's probably a more elegant way of doing it but if you assign a value to an object in the look and put in another `for` loop outside the `while` loop, with a `break` command dependent on the value of that object then it works

Comment: updated with your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (only showing the relevant portions):

```
for (i in 1:n.steps){

   # ...

       break.out.of.for <- FALSE
       while (death == 0) {
        if (ns[13, k-1] > 0) {
            # ...        
        } else {
          if (ns[13, k] == 0) {
            # ...
            break.out.of.for = TRUE
            break
        }
       }
       if (break.out.of.for) {
         break
       }
}
```

Comment: They should not use `break` in the `while` loop. Instead they should use a proper condition in the `while` loop. `death` is never changed inside it. (Possibly they shouldn't use a `while` loop at all. Hard to say without some explanations.)

Comment: @Roland did not check the logic inside, just tried to fulfil OP's requirement.

Comment: That is a fundamental property of a `while` loop. You should break out of it using its condition and not with `if (...) break`.

Comment: sure i agree @Roland

Comment: Thanks - that works for my purposes - the other issues arising here come from me stripping out this from what is much more complex code